# My Page_Load isn't hiding my links in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

So, I have Links on my login page. I have 3 links that aren't suppose to show up until you login. They show up regardless of logging in. I have my Pageload and when I go to the page, it shows up.

Here is my C# code

```
<script runat="server">  

    protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
            AdminLink.Visible = true;
    }

</script>
```

Here is the Login code HyperLink

```
<asp:HyperLink id="AdminLink" NavigateUrl="#" Text="PMO" runat="server"/>
```

Here is my Webconfig

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="ASPX.AUTH" loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" path="/"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Administrator"/>
           <deny users="*"/>  
    </authorization>
```

My **Result** is when you go to the original login page, it doesn't show the links available to click. After login, it loads to the login page with the Links showing. I'm not really sure what's wrong at this point.

Comment: `AdminLink.Visible = true;` sets the link visible. But I don't see anywhere that you had previously set it invisible? I would have expected `<asp:HyperLink id="AdminLink" NavigateUrl="#" Text="PMO" runat="server" Visible="false"/>` in the aspx code. That and/or `if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
            AdminLink.Visible = true; else AdminLink.Visible = false;` in the code-behind.

Comment: @ADyson     I see what you're saying. I was pulling from this website [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2905/Role-based-Security-with-Forms-Authentication) to do this app and it no where mentions that line of code. I thought the same as you did, but I'm not by any means a pro at this so I thought I would pose the experts after I did my search. I'll try your way now and post results.

Comment: @Dyson, it hid the links, but after login it still doesn't show them. No idea at this point. I think maybe some thing is wrong with my cookie?

Comment: have you debugged it, to see what paths the code is taking and where the Visible value is being set / not set?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the link to false on startup? The default behavior is Visible

```
<asp:HyperLink id="AdminLink" NavigateUrl="#" Text="PMO" runat="server" Visible="false"/>
```